# #NAME? Error after creating a custom function for data linkage

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm working on linking historical data sources where the spelling and ordering of geographic place names are not uniform. My approach to this problem is to create a custom Excel function that would remove challenging bits of the name (i.e., punctuation, 'saint', etc.) convert all of the characters in the place name string to numeric values, add them up, while keeping the first letter. That way, the order in which the characters appear should be irrelevant, except for the first letter. This is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Scramble(ByVal str1 As String)
    ' This function is meant to generate a unique index of all the characters used
    ' in the string, regardless of their order. It also removes ambiguous spellings
    Dim count As Long, i As Long, firstLetter As String

    ' convert to upper case
    str1 = UCase(str1)
    ' remove punctuation first
    str1 = Replace(str1, ".", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, ",", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "-", " ")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "'", "")
    ' now ambiguous spellings
    str1 = Replace(str1, "ST ", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "SAINT ", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "MAGNA", "GREAT")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "PARVA", "LESS")
    ' now extract the first letter
    firstLetter = Left(str1, 1)
    ' now prepositions
    str1 = Replace(str1, "AT ", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "IN ", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "THE ", "")
    str1 = Replace(str1, "UPON ", "ON")
    ' make sure to remove spaces last or else the searches will fail
    str1 = Replace(str1, " ", "")

    count = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(str1)
        count = count + Asc(Mid(str1, i, 1))
    Next i
    Scramble = firstLetter & Str(count)
End Function
```

My problem is that, when I call this function in the worksheet, it returns a `#NAME?` error, and it also seems to have caused my `CONCAT` worksheet function to stop working, also calling a `#NAME?` error. I'm sort of at a loss as to what is causing this. Excel VBA doesn't seem to have the usual compiler to catch errors at the source, but I suspect it might be a syntax error in my VBA code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try running it from VBA instead of from a worksheet to see what's causing the problem.  (If necessary, add a breakpoint and step through the code with F8.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by my changing the name of the module from the default `Module1` to a more informative name.